# Any good website to practice translation *to* German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

As per the subject. I see duolingo is mostly about translation **from** German, which is good, but I'd like to practice the other way round. I also speak Spanish if that helps.

Comment: Create a new Duolingo account and select German as your mother tongue...

Comment: That was the first thing I did, but they don't give you that option (so far, at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try using Lang-8. Many people include a copy of the text in their native language in case any part is particularly incomprehensible. So you could always translate a text into German, post it and attach the original English (or Spanish). Also, I'd tell people it's a translation and see if they'd critique it. I don't know it that'll work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Lang-8 looks quite good indeed, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSocial_networking_language_education_websites) has a category with similar websites.  Sadly, I cannot give any information on their quality.